# does removing an answer with upvotes cause a reputation change?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers, up-votes

If I gave an answer with some upvotes and then I remove it, will my acquired reputation decrease proportionally to the upvote's score?

Comment: Maybe, it is flaky.  You'll lose the rep when it is recalculated.  /reputation page for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will decrease.  The real question is when.  Might be instant, but most likely won't be till you manually recalculate or till the next global recalc.

Comment: It's not going to be instant unless you manage to delete right before a global reputation recalc.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was asked (and [jzd's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95076/21960) was accepted), the system has been updated. You should see a near instantaneous change in your total reputation score when you delete an answer with votes.